# Extract features from huge (60000) JSON file directrory into a CSV

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I'm trying to parse a huge collection of JSON files. Around 60000 JSON file (size range 100 KB- 700 MB) total of 1.8 TB, so I made this script which parse JSON file and extract some features and export them in CSV file, it works fine but its extremely slow some of the JSON files take more than 30 minutes to be parsed, I tried to make it faster but I couldn't due to my short Python experience. Is there anyway I can make it faster because I need to parse these huge collection sooner. I'm posting a snippet of my code I know its a little dump.

And here is sample of my JSON files please feel free to check
https://gofile.io/d/vddzHY

```
count1=0
my_file_list = [f for f in glob.glob(r"E:\JsonOrgnized\Pach\*.json")]
final_result = []
for filename in my_file_list:
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as f:
            row = {}
            info = ijson.items(f, 'info')
            f.seek(0)
            for o in info:
                 row['AA-Added']= float(o.get('added'))
                 row['AB-Started']= float(o.get('started'))
                 row['AC-Duration']= o.get('duration')
                 row['AD-Ended']= float(o.get('ended'))

            f.seek(0)
            domains = ijson.items(f, 'network.domains.item')
            domain_count = 0
            for domain in domains:
                domain_count+=1
            row['AE-DomainCount'] = domain_count

            f.seek(0)
            signatures = ijson.items(f, 'signatures.item')
            signature_count = 0
            for signature in signatures:
                signature_count+=1
            row['AF-SignatureCount'] = signature_count

            f.seek(0)
            domains = ijson.items(f, 'behavior.generic.item')
            domain_count = 0
            for domain in domains:
                domain_count+=1
            row['AG-GenericCount'] = domain_count

            f.seek(0)
            apistats = ijson.items(f, 'behavior.apistats')
            apistat_count = 0
            for apistat in apistats:
                for inner_apistat in apistat:
                    apistat_count+=1
            row['AH-ApistatCount'] = apistat_count

            f.seek(0)
            processes = ijson.items(f, 'behavior.processes.item')
            process_count = 0
            for process in processes:
                process_count+=1
            row['AI-ProcessCount'] = process_count

            f.seek(0)
            summaries = ijson.items(f, 'behavior.summary')
            summary_count = 0
            for summary in summaries:
                for inner_summary in summary:
                    summary_count+=1
            row['AJ-SummaryCount'] = summary_count

            f.seek(0)
            apistats_element = ijson.items(f, 'behavior.apistats')
            for inner_apistats in apistats_element:
                for index, inner_fields in inner_apistats.items():
                    row = dict(Counter(row)+Counter(inner_fields))
            
            row['AK-Filename'] = os.path.basename(filename)

            
    except Exception as e:
        #pass
        #print(f"Filename {filename} has issue with {e}")
        row = {}
    
    if row:        
        final_result.append(row) 
    count1+=1
    print("File Number" , count1 , "Is Finished!")
Print("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<DONE>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
```

Comment: You're reading each file eight times - that seems like an obvious opportunity for removing (wasted) time. Have you tried reading+processing each file just once? But didn't you already ask this earlier today, this question seems identical - did your question get closed? Why?

Comment: And please edit a minimal sample of your file into your question __as text__ rather than offsite link which I for one will never click on.

Comment: Your except which ignores the exception is a hazardous approach - could be hiding all sorts of horrors - at least make it print or log the error so you know they are happening.

Comment: @balmy Thanks for your answer , yes its the same question I asked him for help and didn't know he was posting the question so thanks to him for trying to help and thank you for answering

Comment: @JonSG Thank you so much , really appreciated

Comment: How long do those demo files take to process?

Comment: those demo files does not take to much time, I can provide you with files that could take exponential time, some of the files throws an error (json has issue with 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position). let me know if you want me to provide you with them

Comment: @JonSG  please feel free to check this demo  https://gofile.io/d/M2Guu4

Comment: you should process the json file one row at a time from source to target.  make multiple scans to transform the data

Comment: Hey @ray I see that you unaccepted my answer. that is of course fine, but does that mean this is still an open issue and that you are still seeking help on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a little faster and I think cleaner.

We will use one of the more "lower level" calls from `ijson`. and based on the paths we get take some sort of action.

We will store paths of interest and the actions to take when encountered in a little work dictionary.

```
import ijson
import os

def fn_set_value(row, key, value):
    row[key] = value

def fn_increment_count(row, key):
    row[key] = row.get(key, 0) + 1

# ---------------------
# When these keys (tuples) are encountered, we will take the corresponding action.
# ---------------------
work = {
    ("info.added", "number"): lambda row, value: fn_set_value(row, "AA-Added", value),
    ("info.started", "number"): lambda row, value: fn_set_value(row, "AB-Started", value),
    ("info.duration", "number"): lambda row, value: fn_set_value(row, "AC-Duration", value),
    ("info.ended", "number"): lambda row, value: fn_set_value(row, "AD-Ended", value),
    ("network.domains.item", "start_map"): lambda row, value: fn_increment_count(row, "AE-DomainCount"),
    ("signatures.item", "start_map"): lambda row, value: fn_increment_count(row, "AF-SignatureCount"),
    ("behavior.generic.item", "start_map"): lambda row, value: fn_increment_count(row, "AG-GenericCount"),
    ("behavior.apistats", "map_key"): lambda row, value: fn_increment_count(row, "AH-ApistatCount"),
    ("behavior.processes.item", "start_map"): lambda row, value: fn_increment_count(row, "AI-ProcessCount"),
    ("behavior.summary", "map_key"): lambda row, value: fn_increment_count(row, "AJ-SummaryCount"),
}
# ---------------------

# ---------------------
# Your initial set of files
# ---------------------
my_file_list = [
    "d:/temp/foo/report1.json",
    "d:/temp/foo/report2.json",
    "d:/temp/foo/report3.json",
    "d:/temp/foo/report4.json",
    "d:/temp/foo/report5.json"
]
# ---------------------

final_result = []
for index, filename in enumerate(my_file_list):
    print(f"Processing file {index+1} from {filename}")
    try:
        row = {}
        with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
            for i in ijson.parse(f):
                key = (i[0], i[1])
                if key in work.keys():      # if the tuple is an interesting one
                    work[key](row, i[2])    # use it to take an action on row
        row["AK-Filename"] = os.path.basename(filename)
        final_result.append(row)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"\tUnable to process \"{filename}\": {e}")
        # retry with ascii or having stripped out the bad character?
        pass

print("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<DONE>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
print(final_result)
```

This produce this result in a couple of seconds.

```
[
    {
        'AA-Added': Decimal('1631536343.897729'),
        'AB-Started': Decimal('1631536440.728626'),
        'AC-Duration': 21,
        'AD-Ended': Decimal('1631536461.778441'),
        'AE-DomainCount': 3,
        'AF-SignatureCount': 5,
        'AG-GenericCount': 3,
        'AH-ApistatCount': 2,
        'AI-ProcessCount': 3,
        'AJ-SummaryCount': 14,
        'AK-Filename': 'report1.json'
    },
    {
        'AA-Added': Decimal('1631536343.90739'),
        'AB-Started': Decimal('1631536461.849837'),
        'AC-Duration': 12,
        'AD-Ended': Decimal('1631536474.755813'),
        'AE-DomainCount': 3,
        'AF-SignatureCount': 2,
        'AG-GenericCount': 2,
        'AH-ApistatCount': 1,
        'AI-ProcessCount': 2,
        'AJ-SummaryCount': 2,
        'AK-Filename': 'report2.json'
    },
    {
        'AA-Added': Decimal('1631536343.962804'),
        'AB-Started': Decimal('1631536692.972615'),
        'AC-Duration': 312,
        'AD-Ended': Decimal('1631537005.710977'),
        'AE-DomainCount': 4,
        'AF-SignatureCount': 36,
        'AG-GenericCount': 13,
        'AH-ApistatCount': 12,
        'AI-ProcessCount': 13,
        'AJ-SummaryCount': 22,
        'AK-Filename': 'report3.json'
    },
    {
        'AA-Added': Decimal('1631536344.049105'),
        'AB-Started': Decimal('1631537026.918725'),
        'AC-Duration': 316,
        'AD-Ended': Decimal('1631537342.92093'),
        'AE-DomainCount': 3,
        'AF-SignatureCount': 16,
        'AG-GenericCount': 4,
        'AH-ApistatCount': 3,
        'AI-ProcessCount': 4,
        'AJ-SummaryCount': 16,
        'AK-Filename': 'report4.json'
    },
    {
        'AA-Added': Decimal('1631536344.112968'),
        'AB-Started': Decimal('1631537322.81162'),
        'AC-Duration': 14,
        'AD-Ended': Decimal('1631537337.342377'),
        'AE-DomainCount': 3,
        'AF-SignatureCount': 1,
        'AG-GenericCount': 2,
        'AH-ApistatCount': 1,
        'AI-ProcessCount': 2,
        'AJ-SummaryCount': 7,
        'AK-Filename': 'report5.json'
    }
]
```

Comment: Wow, I just tried this script and managed to parse 40 json files(3GB) in less than a minute! incredible ! thank you so much. I got error with 5 files ( 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 56: invalid continuation byte)

Comment: could you please help me overcome this issue , the files are in the link in my reply to you (above) the files names are (report01 ,report06,report11,report12,report16)

Comment: sure thing I'll take a look in a few minutes

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: any update please ?

Comment: File 06 contains text like `\ude90` that is apparently being treated as a Unicode escape sequence and the parser is unable to deal with it. Are you sure your original file is utf-8?

Comment: I was off stack overflow last two days, my bad was about to mark it as the solution but forgot to. if you ever come to a solution to the UTF-8 problem just let me know please